# How to get corresponding values of a key in a JSON object in python where keys are in a different array

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a JSON object which looks like this

```
{
'stats': {
    'stats_fields': {}
},
'responseHeader': {
    'stats': 0,
    'QTime': 312
},
'response': {
    'start': 0,
    'maxScore': 4.224531,
    'nmFond': 10,
    'docs': [{
        'ml(div(map(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),0,100,abs(hpsaScore_alpha),100),100),ml(0.2,div(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),map(hpsaScore_alpha,0,0,1,hpsaScore_alpha))))': 0.14139599,
        'id': '635017352776'
    }, {
        'ml(div(map(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),0,100,abs(hpsaScore_alpha),100),100),ml(0.2,div(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),map(hpsaScore_alpha,0,0,1,hpsaScore_alpha))))': 0.13736124,
        'id': '626248286912'
    }, {
        'ml(div(map(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),0,100,abs(hpsaScore_alpha),100),100),ml(0.2,div(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),map(hpsaScore_alpha,0,0,1,hpsaScore_alpha))))': 0.14090206,
        'id': '667202821955'
    }, {
        'ml(div(map(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),0,100,abs(hpsaScore_alpha),100),100),ml(0.2,div(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),map(hpsaScore_alpha,0,0,1,hpsaScore_alpha))))': 0.13128135,
        'id': '652653090703'
    }, {
        'ml(div(map(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),0,100,abs(hpsaScore_alpha),100),100),ml(0.2,div(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),map(hpsaScore_alpha,0,0,1,hpsaScore_alpha))))': 0.15008019,
        'id': '673173069540'
    }, {
        'ml(div(map(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),0,100,abs(hpsaScore_alpha),100),100),ml(0.2,div(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),map(hpsaScore_alpha,0,0,1,hpsaScore_alpha))))': 0.13817552,
        'id': '651864037354'
    }, {
        'ml(div(map(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),0,100,abs(hpsaScore_alpha),100),100),ml(0.2,div(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),map(hpsaScore_alpha,0,0,1,hpsaScore_alpha))))': 0.1015507,
        'id': '366140762'
    }, {
        'ml(div(map(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),0,100,abs(hpsaScore_alpha),100),100),ml(0.2,div(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),map(hpsaScore_alpha,0,0,1,hpsaScore_alpha))))': 0.049298372,
        'id': '621955821828'
    }, {
        'ml(div(map(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),0,100,abs(hpsaScore_alpha),100),100),ml(0.2,div(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),map(hpsaScore_alpha,0,0,1,hpsaScore_alpha))))': 0.037345234,
        'id': '627999851992'
    }, {
        'ml(div(map(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),0,100,abs(hpsaScore_alpha),100),100),ml(0.2,div(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),map(hpsaScore_alpha,0,0,1,hpsaScore_alpha))))': 0.03293659,
        'id': '647972845012'
    }]
}
}
```

I have another array having the Ids which looks like this

[626248286912, 366140762, 627999851992, 667202821955, 621955821828, 652653090703, 647972845012, 673173069540, 635017352776, 651864037354]

now i want to create an array having the value of key `ml(div(map(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),0,100,abs(hpsaScore_alpha),100),100),ml(0.2,div(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),map(hpsaScore_alpha,0,0,1,hpsaScore_alpha))))` in the same order as the Ids in the second array . Is there a more efffcient way to do it in python than iterating and comparing the Ids in the json object

Answer (score 1):

First your data is not really `json` because strings are protected by single quotes and `json` expects double quotes.

That can be workarounded by using `ast.literal_eval` for now.

So, I create `d` using `ast.literal_eval` so data is correctly converted to python native structure.

Then, I create a dictionary with key=id (as integer) and value as the value beared by the key different from `id` (using a nested generator comprehension that I consume using `next` to get the sole element)

After that, it's easy to query each value of the dictionary and compose the list in the required order.

Code:

```
import ast

js = """{
'stats': {
    'stats_fields': {}
},
'responseHeader': {
    'stats': 0,
    'QTime': 312
},
'response': {
    'start': 0,
    'maxScore': 4.224531,
    'nmFond': 10,
    'docs': [{
        'ml(div(map(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),0,100,abs(hpsaScore_alpha),100),100),ml(0.2,div(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),map(hpsaScore_alpha,0,0,1,hpsaScore_alpha))))': 0.14139599,
        'id': '635017352776'
    }, {
        'ml(div(map(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),0,100,abs(hpsaScore_alpha),100),100),ml(0.2,div(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),map(hpsaScore_alpha,0,0,1,hpsaScore_alpha))))': 0.13736124,
        'id': '626248286912'
    }, {
        'ml(div(map(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),0,100,abs(hpsaScore_alpha),100),100),ml(0.2,div(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),map(hpsaScore_alpha,0,0,1,hpsaScore_alpha))))': 0.14090206,
        'id': '667202821955'
    }, {
        'ml(div(map(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),0,100,abs(hpsaScore_alpha),100),100),ml(0.2,div(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),map(hpsaScore_alpha,0,0,1,hpsaScore_alpha))))': 0.13128135,
        'id': '652653090703'
    }, {
        'ml(div(map(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),0,100,abs(hpsaScore_alpha),100),100),ml(0.2,div(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),map(hpsaScore_alpha,0,0,1,hpsaScore_alpha))))': 0.15008019,
        'id': '673173069540'
    }, {
        'ml(div(map(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),0,100,abs(hpsaScore_alpha),100),100),ml(0.2,div(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),map(hpsaScore_alpha,0,0,1,hpsaScore_alpha))))': 0.13817552,
        'id': '651864037354'
    }, {
        'ml(div(map(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),0,100,abs(hpsaScore_alpha),100),100),ml(0.2,div(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),map(hpsaScore_alpha,0,0,1,hpsaScore_alpha))))': 0.1015507,
        'id': '366140762'
    }, {
        'ml(div(map(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),0,100,abs(hpsaScore_alpha),100),100),ml(0.2,div(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),map(hpsaScore_alpha,0,0,1,hpsaScore_alpha))))': 0.049298372,
        'id': '621955821828'
    }, {
        'ml(div(map(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),0,100,abs(hpsaScore_alpha),100),100),ml(0.2,div(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),map(hpsaScore_alpha,0,0,1,hpsaScore_alpha))))': 0.037345234,
        'id': '627999851992'
    }, {
        'ml(div(map(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),0,100,abs(hpsaScore_alpha),100),100),ml(0.2,div(abs(hpsaScore_alpha),map(hpsaScore_alpha,0,0,1,hpsaScore_alpha))))': 0.03293659,
        'id': '647972845012'
    }]
}
}"""

idlist = [626248286912, 366140762, 627999851992, 667202821955, 621955821828, 652653090703, 647972845012, 673173069540, 635017352776, 651864037354]

d = ast.literal_eval(js)
by_id = {int(sd['id']):next(v for v in sd.values() if v!=sd['id']) for sd in d['response']['docs']}

result = [(a,by_id[a]) for a in idlist]
print(result)
```

result (if you just want the values and not the tuples do: `[by_id[a] for a in idlist]`):

```
[(626248286912, 0.13736124), (366140762, 0.1015507), (627999851992, 0.037345234), (667202821955, 0.14090206), (621955821828, 0.049298372), (652653090703, 0.13128135), (647972845012, 0.03293659), (673173069540, 0.15008019), (635017352776, 0.14139599), (651864037354, 0.13817552)]
```

Comment: Fabre . Thanks . The by_id objects gives the correct response {626248286912: 0.13736124, 667202821955: 0.14090206, 673173069540: 0.15008019, 635017352776: 0.14139599, 652653090703: 0.13128135, 647972845012: 0.03293659, 627999851992: 0.037345234, 621955821828: 0.049298372, 366140762: 0.1015507, 673543923100: 0.14060774} But result gives a KeyError 'i' . I don't know python so if its a dumb question pls excuse

Comment: What i think is that by_id isn't really a key value object as it should have been if we are accessing it by index ?

Comment: that's because you're not using `idlist` as input but something else. Copy the exact provided code snippet I provided in a python file and run it, you'll get the correct result. And it's not accessing by index: `[a]` is accessing the key `a` of a dictionnary. It's the same syntax, but they are not indexes.